# Yandex email account gets blocked even though authenticated by app password

Tags: php, email, imap, yandex

I have a system that its business logic relies on reading incoming mails to email accounts so that the operations could be made automated.
An app password is generated and the imap access is enabled from the settings of every email account.
The emails are created on Yandex mail.
Even though the initial imap connection is checked and confirmed by the system, for some unknown reasons, Yandex is blocking all access to the account. At browser login, asks for captcha and sms verification, also imap access is blocked.

I have read Yandex mail documentation also, however could not find the reason why this is happening. What could be the reason of this?

Comment: Are you complying with Yandex's terms of service? It's possible that they don't want their email servers being used in this fashion.

Comment: Don't you think it is absurd that it authenticates the account via credentials in the first place then suddenly marks the account as it has suspicious login activity?

Comment: They could think that you're operating some sort of automated spamming system or something; I'm having difficulty finding their ToS, but if their email system is intended for human use, they might block automated sign-ins entirely.

Comment: There are similar operations that I know of that are being run. No issues there, the same sort of activity being made.
I read on Terms of Yandex that invalid login attempts from a network that tries to authenticate with failure might also result in this outcome. Could it be the IP block that  the server runs on?

Comment: I don't know, it's outside of my area of expertise. Have you considered contacting their customer service, assuming that your service complies with their ToS?

Comment: Not yet, having more faith in the community :)